# redirect query to folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the url with:

http://site.com/consulting/search.php?searchterm59

And would like to process it to search.php but url should like this:

http://site.com/consulting/search/searchterm59

I have also tried this ones:

I have tried this ones

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/constulting/search\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com/consulting/search/%1 [R=302,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ search.php$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?$ search.php?%1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /(.*)/search.*
RewriteRule .*        %1/%{QUERY_STRING}?     [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I think that he wants to save QUERY_STRING value

Comment: Well, the only way to know is waiting for the OP to say something, if he says something someday. The question is not clear enough. You might be right, though.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# for external redirect to /consulting/search/searchterm59
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(constulting/search)\.php\?([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]

# for internal forward to /consulting/search.php?searchterm59
RewriteRule ^(constulting/search)/(.*)$ /$1.php?$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```